# Handler laggs the App

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

Im programming a Music Player with a Seekbar.To manage it im using an Handler with a Runnable which does it update. Somehow it is lagging my UI . How can I stop this lag ?

OnCreate:

```
mHandler  = new Handler();
```

When Im playing a Song:

```
 public static void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }
```

My Runnable:

```
private static Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

             try {
             long totalDuration = songService.getTotalDuration();
             int currentDuration = songService.getCurrentDuration();

             // Displaying Total Duration time
             player_time_length.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));

             // Displaying time completed playing
             player_time_current.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

             // Updating progress bar
             int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));

             SB_song.setProgress(currentDuration);

             // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
             mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
             }catch(Exception e){}
         }
      };
```

How can I prevent this lagg in my App ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag is because the `Runnable` is executing in the `UI Thread`. To reduce or remove the lag, you have to reduce the amount of work you do inside the `Runnable`.

One thing that you can do is to remove `long totalDuration = songService.getTotalDuration();` from the `Runnable` and instead, put it outside, like I do in my music player.

I could add more to this answer if you included the "utils" methods that you're using to convert milliseconds to human readable time.

Comment: That helped ! But I also changed sth diffrent : "mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);" I actually misstyped here .This calls my handler every 100ms which is not needed.I added one 0 and now its every 1 sec which works like a charm  now  :D

Comment: @AhmetKazaman It's 100ms in mine, and there's absolutely no lag. I like the seekbar updation to look smooth so it's 100ms. Anyway, good to know your problem is solved.

Comment: Have a new problem maybe u got an Idea because u made allready an Music Player  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351763/listview-lags-with-music-album-pictures

Answer (score 0):

I would say its because its running on the UI Thread which laggs. But you have to use UI elements so another Thread is not possible .. Im right ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text view is not set to wrap_content. That will trigger a layout pass each time you call setText.