# ListView lags with Music Album pictures

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm building a music player which should have a listView with title-artistname and Image of the albumcover. This seems to get very laggy. How can I improve performance?

My function to get these pictures is like this:

```
public static Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context,Long album_id){
  Bitmap bm = null;
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
try{
    final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    if (pfd != null){
        FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
        pfd = null;
        fd = null;
    }
} catch(Error ee){bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.cd_128x128); }
catch (Exception e) { bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.cd_128x128);}
return bm;}
```

If I do this everytime in my getView function the App kills itself. So I tried to save them first in a Arraylist of Bitmaps but this takes too long. I already tried with  a Viewholder but this really doesn't affect the performance.

My getview looks like this

```
`@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rview = view;
        holder = null;


        if (rview == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_song, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder(rview);
            rview.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rview.getTag();
        }


        holder.imgAlbumart.setImageBitmap(Music.getAlbumart(context, Long.valueOf(AL_songlist.get(position).getAlbumID())));

        holder.txtTitle.setText(AL_songlist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(AL_songlist.get(position).getArtist());


        return rview;
        }`
```

EDIT: [image]

It's the same when I try it through.

> android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART

Comment: Tip: use a library that loads the images asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use my `AlbumArtLoader.java`. I got it from android developers website but can't find the page. I modified it to make it smoother than the provided code.

```
/* Loads images smoothly in ListView */


public class AlbumArtLoader {
    private Context ctx;
    private int artSize;
    private final Bitmap mPlaceHolderBitmap;
    private Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[2];
    public AlbumArtLoader(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        artSize = c.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.albumart_size);
        mPlaceHolderBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.transparent);
        mPlaceHolderBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPlaceHolderBitmap, artSize, artSize, false);
        drawables[0] = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap);
    }
    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, TransitionDrawable> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private String path;
        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }
        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected TransitionDrawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            path = params[0];
            // TransitionDrawable let you to make a crossfade animation between 2 drawables
            // It increase the sensation of smoothness
            TransitionDrawable td = null;

            // The albumart_unknown bitmap is recreated for each album without album art to maintain even scrolling
            if(path == null) {
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.albumart_unknown), artSize, artSize, true);
                drawables[1] = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), b);
            } else {
                Bitmap b;
                try {
                    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path), artSize, artSize, true);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.albumart_unknown), artSize, artSize, true);
                }
                drawables[1] = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), b);
            }
            td = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
            td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
             return td;
        }
        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(TransitionDrawable td) {
            if(isCancelled()) {
                td = null;
            }
            if(imageViewReference != null && td != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
                if(this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
                    td.startTransition(200);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadBitmap(String path, ImageView imageView) {
        if(cancelPotentialWork(path, imageView)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(ctx.getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            task.execute(path);
        }
    }

    static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;
        public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
            super(res, bitmap);
            bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
        }
        public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
            return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(String path, ImageView imageView) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        if(bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final String bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.path;
            // If bitmapData is not yet set or it differs from the new data
            if(bitmapData == null || bitmapData != path) {
                // Cancel previous task
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
        // The same work is already in progress
                return false;
            }
        }
        // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
        return true;
    }

    // Helper method
    private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if(imageView != null) {
            final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

To use it, create an `AlbumArtLoader` instance in your `Adapter`

```
AlbumArtLoader mArtLoader;
```

Instantiate it using

```
mArtLoader = new AlbumArtLoader(context);
```

inside your`Adapter` constructor, which receives `Context` from your `Activity`.

Then in `getView()`

```
mArtLoader.loadBitmap(pathToAlbumArt, vh.imgAlbumart);
```

EXTRA: To get album art path from your cursor

```
int artColumnIndex = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);

if(albumCursor!=null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String artPath = albumCursor.getString(artColumnIndex);
    }  while (albumCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But why :  "BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.transparent);" ? Why is it transparent, and how does it look like ? And what dimen albumart_size are you using ?

Comment: @AhmetKazaman The transparent drawable is just a transparent png file in your drawable folder. It's used because TransitionDrawable requires at least 2 drawables for fading effect. I'm using 67dp for album art size.

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses ! But somehow it just load the default drawables. The path im passing through the function is like : "/storage/extSdCard/Musik/08-Ice Cube-I Rep That West.mp3".Does it need a path to the albumart ?

Comment: @AhmetKazaman You need the path to the album art. I get it during the Album database query by using `String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART, MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS};` as the **projection** in the **query()** method. Here `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART` is for Album Art path.

Comment: Thanks David ! God bless you and I really love this class ! Cheers from Germany <3

Comment: @AhmetKazaman You're welcome! :) I'm just glad that I'm now able to help others as I have been helped before on StackOverflow. Good luck with your app!

Comment: can it be that MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART is an Integer ? just a question btw ^^ Do I have to convert it ?

Comment: @AhmetKazaman You get the album art path String the same way you get the album id string from the Cursor returned from the query() method.

Comment: I added a screenshot in my first post

Comment: @AhmetKazaman I added more to my answer. I hope you get the idea from the code snippet.

Comment: Your simply awesome !

Answer (score 0):

You can use AQuery for Asynchronous Image Load:

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI